# which one is more appropriate, "Following" or "Further to"

Tags: meaning, expressions

Is it OK to say "**Following** the task that has been given to us, I would like to invite you to a meeting"?

Or should I say "**Further to** the task that has been given to us, I would like to invite you to a meeting"?

Which one is more appropriate?

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to express and whether or not you're open to a different way of phrasing it than the two you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

'Following' means coming after.

'Further to' means that we are 'furthering' (moving forward) the task.

So appropriate sentences would be:

> "Following the publication of the XYZ report, I would like to invite
>   you to a celebration of its success"

or

> "Further to the publication of the XYZ report, I would like to invite
>   you to a planning meeting at which we will decide its
>   contents"

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, both are somewhat awkward.  I much prefer "***[pursuant to](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pursuant)***".

> (**pursuant to**) *formal*
>   In accordance with (a law or a legal document or resolution):
>   *'the local authority applied for care orders pursuant to section 31 of the Children Act 1989'*

In your example,

> Pursuant to the task that has been given to us, I would like to invite you to a meeting.

Comment: Pursuant to means in accordance with, as you said. The OP wants a meeting to discuss the task, not a meeting in accordance with the task.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction nb: i agree you that the question needs a bit of clarification, which provide some nuance.  but as straightforward reading, using the former as the purpose or reference point for the latter part, it's no different than saying (e.g.), "pursuant to your instructions, i will meet with the client."  the task at hand is the point of having the meeting; presumably the meeting will be about the task.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean *after*, say _

- **after**.

if you simply mean *in connection with*, say

- **regarding**.

If you mean *in order to help us accomplish* (and you want to use some form of "further"), say

- **in furtherance of**
  (although this sounds quite academic in tone, if not downright stuffy. You might better put it: *to help us accomplish*.)

Answer (score 0):

Both are too formal, even though correct, of course.

I'd say managers would be more likely to say these days:

***Now that*** the task has been given to us, I would like to invite you to a meeting.